# Android Emulator not coming up on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have `Ubuntu 12.04` and the `java 1.7`.

The problem is that the `emulator` won't start whatever I try. I have also tried changing the `java` to Open `Jdk 6` but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Try to launch it via command `emulator -avd <name>` and post the error message.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting.

Comment: Launch it via command-line and post the log.

Comment: This is what came up when i tried it through command line: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming `tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so` to `tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so.xxx` has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get::

Download the package

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html. Check the the link under TroubleShooting linux